# How to filter Array in ToDo App in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I am new to React Js. I created a simple todo app which stores data in an array. I also added pagination and delete options. Now I want to add a search field. I added an input field when a type input they show me error:

> TypeError: item.toLowerCase is not a function

My code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    class Search  extends Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props)
                this.state = {
                    filtered: []
                }
                this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                this.setState({
                  filtered: this.props.listItems  //props from other page
                });
              }
              componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
                this.setState({
                  filtered: nextProps.listItems
                });
              }
              handleChange(e) {
                // Variable to hold the original version of the list
            let currentList = [];
                // Variable to hold the filtered list before putting into state
            let newList = [];

                // If the search bar isn't empty
            if (e.target.value !== "") {

                    // Assign the original list to currentList
              currentList = this.props.listItems;

                    // Use .filter() to determine which items should be displayed
                    // based on the search terms
              newList = currentList.filter(item => {

                // change current item to lowercase
                const lc = item.toLowerCase();

                // change search term to lowercase
                const filter = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
                return lc.includes(filter);
              });
            } else {
                    // If the search bar is empty, set newList to original task list
              newList = this.props.listItems;
            }
                // Set the filtered state based on what our rules added to newList
            this.setState({
              filtered: newList
            });
          }
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                     <input type="text" className="input" onChange={this.handleChange} 
                     placeholder="Search..." />
                    {this.props.btton}
                    {this.props.listItems}

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default Search
```

Comment: Have you tried checking with is item during the filter? Try console.log the result or debugging.  My guess is item is not the object you are expecting and that is why you are seeing the error.

Comment: @SajidAli we are not here to fix your code. We are here to help you understand where the problem is. Did you do what tomerpacific told you to do so that you can move on with your debugging?

Comment: @SajidAli how does the `currentList` array look like? Mind posting a sample?